# Is the number of possible N-Dimensional subspaces always 1 when working in N-Dimensional ambient space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

For instance, if I have two or more $2$D vectors in $2$D ambient space, will their subspace always be defined as the entire cartesian plane given that none of the vectors are colinear nor zero vectors?

Additionally, if I had $N$ or more ND vectors in ND ambient space, would the number of possible subspaces still only remain 1, that being the entire ambient space, again, given that none of the vectors are colinear or zeros

Comment: Consider the case where you have three elements of $\mathbb{R}^3$, but all three elements lay on a common plane.

Comment: @William Ok, for instance, [1 2 0], [3 6 0] and [4 6 0].  All of these vectors would remain on the XY plane.  Does that mean that their subspace be defined as the entire XY plane?

Comment: Precisely. For reference, the common terminologu for what you call “their subspace” is known as the *span* of the according vectors.

Comment: @William Thank you, this all makes sense.  But just for clarity, despite the vectors in my example being in $\mathbb{R}^3$, it would still be considered a $2$D subspace regardless of the $3$D ambient space, right?

Comment: your title question is clearly true, there are a few ways of proving this, however, in order for your subspace to be N-dimensional though you need your vectors to be linearly independent.
Now every maximal independent set is a basis, and you know by assumption that the ambient space has dimension N so any linear independent set with N elements is a basis, and so your subspace is the whole space. (i.e. the previous comments just pointed out that if your vectors are linearly dependent your subspace wont be N dimensional)